# gRPC Distributed Servers - Keeping Packet Order

Tags: grpc

I'm trying out gRPC as a solution to a problem and im wondering if its possible to do that, i have not found anything regarding this.

Ill exemplify the problem

Let's say i have a distributed server A of 100 nodes.

Those servers are going to call another server B, which is a single node, using gRPC calls. Each node has a pool of connections open to server B.

The goal is to make sure server B receives all requests in order. Since latency can vary, if two nodes of server A sends requests almost at the same time, it would be possible to receive those requests in an incorrect order ?

Would apreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

inter stream order is not guaranteed in http2 layer. your best bet is client generates a sequence number (this is yet another very hard problem), so you can handle it in order on the server side (B).
Note that telling order of request itself is very hard unless you have an atomic clock.

this problem usually means you are trying solve the actual problem in wrong way. with some legacy code this can be unavoidable, but better to fix underlying issue rather than fix it in hacky way or something impossible.